# How do I stop the "Connected as Installer" when connecting to computer? (LG G3 Lollipop)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, charging, mtp, lg-g3

When I connect my LG G3 running Lollipop to my Mac, the phone connects as an installer. The Verizon Mobile finder window pops up and my phone notifies me it's connected as an installer.

I have changed the USB connection option to "charge only", but the phone continues to pop up the Verizon Mobile window periodically. It's not really running as "charge only"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It mounts a disk or something, right ?